# How to relate angular 6 login with spring login

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, angular6

it's my first question here in stackoverflow.
I'll try to explain my problem as much comprensible as possible.

I'm trying to develop a web-app with Java 8 using spring(not spring-boot), hibernate and angular 6. I already wrote back-end side (spring and hibernate), my entities work perfectly with my db (MySQL). I divided the back-end side into 3 maven modules (persistance (entities-repositories), service, web(controllers)) and added a front-end maven module with Angular 6.

And here there is my problem.
I am not able to connect angular with spring, in particular with spring security. I cut and paste the dist folder of angular inside src>main>webapp package and i cant and/or i dont know how to reach the angular's login page using spring security. I mean, i dont know how to relate angular login with spring login.

In the spring security config xml i wrote

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <form-login />
    <logout />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="{noop}admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="{noop}user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

i don't know how to relate the spring login page with my angular's login page, because the angular login page is not inside into dist folder.

Here there is the structure of my project:

```
myproject
----myproject-ng (angulars folder)

----myproject-persistence
--------entities
--------repositories

----myproject-service
--------serivices

----myproject-web
--------controllers
--------webapp
------------myproject-ng(angulars dist folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally AngularJs 6 Project should run independent of the backend microservice. You will have to enable Cross Origin request in controller by @CrossOrigin annotation.